# Would a non-separable position momentum wavefunction really violate the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, phase-space

I've seen it claimed on here that a position momentum wavefunction would violate the uncertainty principle.  I would interpret as saying that position momentum wavefunctions that are not separable with respect to position and momentum violate the uncertainty principle seeing as a position momentum wavefunction that is separable could just be treated as a position wavefunction and a momentum wavefunction.

Something though that makes me skeptical of the claim that a non separable position momentum wavefunctions really violate the uncertainty principle is that I've seen people claim before that something implies something that it doesn't actually imply  For instance in classical physics I've seen people incorrectly claim that Bertrand's Law implies that inverse square forces are the only ones, in which stable orbits are possible.  One way I've seen people claim that a position momentum wavefunction would violate the uncertainty principle is to point out that you cannot know the momentum if based on observed positions because the uncertainty in momentum goes up as the uncertainty in position goes down.  The problem with this argument is that while determining an exact momentum from position would violate the uncertainty it isn't really explained how having an non separable position momentum wavefunction would imply that you could find an exact momentum for a particle from it's position so the conclusion doesn't seem to follow from the premises.  Finding an example of an instance, in which a position momentum wavefunction would violate the uncertainty principle isn't really useful for showing that all such wavefunctions would, instead it's more useful to look for a counter example of a non separable position momentum wavefunction that does not violate the uncertainty principle as it only takes one such counter example to disprove the claim that non separable position momentum wavefunctions do not violate the uncertainty principle.

A few useful criteria for a candidate for counter example to the claim that non separable position wavefunctions always violate the uncertainty principle, $\Psi(x,p)$ is to make sure that the wavefunction is square integrable.  Also ideally I would want to construct a wavefunction that is also a function of time, however I suspect this would be enough to define a potential function $V(x,p,t)$ and I don't know in this case how to make sure that the potential function has real values everywhere so I'll set time to $0$ for a wavefunction $\Psi(x,p,0)$, since $\Psi(x,p,0)$ should be sufficient for a counter example.  As I understand it the uncertainty for a wavefunction is proportional to how spread out it is in position and momentum space.  I don't know how the way to calculate the exact uncertainty given a wave function, however fortunately the uncertainty principle only sets a minimum on the uncertainty of position and momentum, meaning that if I want to try to get my wavefunction $\Psi(x,p)$ to obey the uncertainty principle I can try to intentionally make the wavefunction more spread out in position and momentum space than it needs to be in order to obey the uncertainty principle.

The function $e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ is non separable, has a non $0$ value everywhere, and is also square integrable.  Also when graphing the function it looks like when looking at the cross sections of the function perpendicular to the x axis, they become more and more spread out in the y direction, the further you get from $x=0$  This makes this function look like the perfect candidate for constructing a counter example to the claim that non separable position momentum wavefunctions violate the uncertainty principle.

To construct the wavefunction $\Psi(x,p,0)$ I start by changing the above equation to $e^{-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{p^2}{b^2}}}$.  To try to be as confident as possible that this wavefunction is spread out enough in position and momentum space I will set a and b to have very large values.  For instance I set $a=1AU$ with AU standing for astronomical unit.  I also set $9*10^{-10}kgm/s$ producing a wavefunction

$$\Psi(x,p,0)=e^{-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(1AU)^2}+\frac{p^2}{(9*10^{-10}kmm/s)^2}}}$$

Now if any wave function $\Psi(x,p,0)$ that is non separable violates the uncertainty principle then the above wavefunction that I constructed needs to violate the uncertainty principle however given how much it is spread out in position and momentum space I'm not sure how this wavefunction violates the uncertainty principle, and even if the issue is that it isn't spread out enough, this should be easy to fix by increasing the values of a and b.

If the above equation does violate the uncertainty principle then I would ask how specifically does it?  If it's because it implies that uncertainty in momentum doesn't go up when uncertainty in position goes down how specifically does it imply that?  If it implies that you can derive an exact momentum for a particle from a measured position how does it imply that when it looks like the momentum can be anything given a measured position?

Comment: What do you mean by a position momentum wave function or non separable position momentum wave function? Maybe you’re interested in the phase space formulations of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Jagerber48 what I mean by a non separable position momentum wavefunction is one that is not the product of a position wavefunction and a momentum wavefunction, while a separable position wavefunction would be the product of a position wavefunction and a momentum wavefunction.

Comment: What is a position momentum wave function? Is this for a single particle?

Comment: For a single particle you can *either* represent the wavefunction in the position basis, *or* in the momentum basis. You should never write down a wavefunction that contains both position and momentum. There *are* formulations of quantum mechanics where both position and momentum can appear, as @Jagerber48 is hinting at, but here the appropriate objects to talk about are [Wigner quasiprobability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution), not wavefunctions

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider your hypothetical position-momentum wavefunction. The reason why people say that it would violate the uncertainty principle is that it does.

Let's consider evaluating the probability that the particle is found between $x_0,x_0+\Delta x$ *and* moving at the momentum that lies between $p_0 + \Delta p$.

This would be given by $\int_{p_0}^{p_0+\Delta p}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}\ \vert \psi(x,p)\vert^2 dx\ dp$. Now, for small enough $\Delta x,\Delta p$, this could be approximated to $\vert \psi(x_0,p_0)\vert^2 \Delta x\ \Delta p$. This needs to vanish for $\Delta x\Delta p < \hbar/2$ for the uncertainty principle to be satisfied. However, $x_0,p_0$ are generic and thus, for this to be true, $\psi(x_0,p_0)$ would need to vanish everywhere --  rendering it non-normalizable. In other words, such a "position-momentum wavefunction" cannot exist. As you can see, the specific form of the $\psi$ that you cook up, however cleverly, doesn't matter.

The principled reason behind this result is simply that a wavefunction $\psi(a,b,c,...)$ is the probability amplitude that the system, upon the simultaneous measurement of operators $A,B,C,...$, would give the answers $a,b,c...$. Since you cannot measure $X,P$ simultaneously, there is no object called the position-momentum wavefunction $\psi(x,p)$ that can be meaningfully constructed.

As pointed out in the comments, what you can do is contruct a quasi-probability distribution function $W(x,p)$ which has the property that $\int dx\ W(x,p) = \vert \psi(p)\vert^2$ and $\int dp\ W(x,p) = \vert\psi(x)\vert^2$. See, [Wigner quasi-probability distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution).